# PHP Parse.com retrieving data from a column with a pointer to another table

Tags: php, parse-platform

Am using parse.com php sdk.

Am having issues with retrieving data from a pointer that is in a column in a table called Product that has multiple columns.
(city, label,country,brand....)

'brand' is a column holding pointers to datas in the table 'Brands' .

In my php code i have set a Class called 'Brand' that extends ParseObject.

```
class Brand extends ParseObject  {

public static $parseClassName = 'Brands';

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct($parseClassName);
}
public function getIdBrand(){
    return $this->getObjectId();
}

public function getName(){
    return $this->get('name');
}

public function setName($name){
    return $this->set('name',$name);
}

public function getDescription(){
    return $this->get('description');
}

public function setDescription($description){
    return $this->set('description',$description);
}

public function save(){
    if(!getName() && !getDescription()){
        echo 'Brand can\'t be saved';
    }else{
        parent::save();
    }
}

function showBrand() {
    echo 'Brand[' . getIdBrand() . ', ' . getName() . ', ' . getDescription()  . ']';
}
```

}

My class Product extends ParseObject.

```
class Product extends ParseObject {

public static $parseClassName = 'Product';

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct ( $parseClassName );
}
public function getIdProduct() {
    return $this->getObjectId ();
}

// --------------
// other getter & setters
// --------------


/**
 * 
 * @return Brand
 */
public function getBrand() {
    return $this->get( 'brand' );
}

public function setBrand($brand) {
    return $this->set ( 'brand', $brand );
}


// --------------
// other getter & setters
// --------------
```

I then have a php file in which i get all the products while specifying the user to whom they belong.

```
$currentUser = ParseUser::getCurrentUser();
$query = new ParseQuery(Product::$parseClassName);
$query->equalTo("user", $currentUser);
$results = $query->find();
```

Then i proceed to get the data of each product.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++) {
$product = $results[$i];
$brand = $results[$i]->get('brand');
echo 'brand name = '.$brand->getName().',';
.........}
```

My issue is that i can't get the brand name.
It only sends me an empty value.

When doing  ==> `var_dump($results[$i]->get('brand'));`
I get the following results

```
object(Brand)#6 (9) { ["serverData":protected]=> array(0) { }
["operationSet":protected]=> array(0) { }
["estimatedData":"Parse\ParseObject":private]=> array(0) { } 
["dataAvailability":"Parse\ParseObject":private]=> array(0) { }
["className":"Parse\ParseObject":private]=> string(6) "Brands"
["objectId":"Parse\ParseObject":private]=> NULL
["createdAt":"Parse\ParseObject":private]=> NULL
["updatedAt":"Parse\ParseObject":private]=> NULL
["hasBeenFetched":"Parse\ParseObject":private]=> bool(true) }
```

Can you advise me on how to retrieve the data in the object(Brand).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find an answer to my problem.

In my php project, i went to the folder where the ParseObject.php was and i updated the function

```
mergeFromServer($data, $completeData = true)
```

I added at the beginning of the foreach this code :

```
            // If we have a column in our table that has a pointer to data in another table
            // The data in our column will be considered as an array.
            // In that array there is the objectId,
            // We then transform that array to a string containing the objectId
            // We will later on do a query to get the data associated to our column 
            if(is_array($value)){
                if(!is_null($value['objectId'])){
                    $value = $value['objectId'];
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

After hours of researching again i found out that there was an easier way to get the data in the column which was a pointer.

I had to add the 'includeKey' in my query.

```
$currentUser = ParseUser::getCurrentUser();
$query = new ParseQuery(Product::$parseClassName);
$query->includeKey("brand");
$query->equalTo("user", $currentUser);
$results = $query->find();
```